# Why is my COM method returning an incorrect value?

Tags: .net, com, mfc

I have a COM method which returns a MFC `CRect`:

```
GetMFCRect(LONG* pRect)
*((CRect*)pRect) = m_currentRect;
```

In my .NET application I try the following:

```
int pointer = new int();
Rectangle rc;
IntPtr pIntResult;
unsafe
{
    int* p = &pointer;
    _COMobj.GetMFCRect(ref *p);
    pIntResult = new IntPtr(p);
    rc = (Rectangle)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pintResult, typeof(Rectangle));
}
```

But `rc` has the wrong values. What is wrong with this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx) is a rather simple structure, and has no casting or conversion from CRect; what you see as values, there, are most probably pointers in the m_currentRect's VTable.
As a possible solution I would pass a GDI RECT structure, that is much safer, or directly the four coordinates.